# Onde consigo o código fonte do Android?

Tags: android, segurança

Estou escrevendo uma documentação, na qual preciso saber qual o código fonte para que uma aplicação possa checar todo o o dispositivo móvel, atrás de configurações que o usuário não realizou, por exemplo:

- se configurou uma senha na tela inicial;
- se criptografou o cartão de memória;
- aplicativos que consumem muita energia;
- aplicativos maliciosos que solicitam ativar o GPS sem utilizar;
- deixar o Bluetooth ativado sem senha;
- utilizar um antivírus;
- realizar ancoragem do dispositivo móvel sem senha e;
- avisar ao usuário aplicativos maliciosos.

Onde acho esses códigos?

Comment: Você quer os fontes do Android? Pra que? Para isto que você está falando ele será bem pouco útil.

Comment: Olá, Estou estudando segurança em dispositivo móvel, e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para saber como funciona a segurança em dispositivo móvel. No caso quando mandasse a aplicação checar: se configurou uma senha na tela inicial;
se criptografou o cartão de memória;
aplicativos que consumem muita energia;
aplicativos maliciosos que solicitam ativar o GPS sem utilizar;
deixar o Bluetooth ativado sem senha;
utilizar um antivírus;
realizar ancoragem do dispositivo móvel sem senha e;
avisar ao usuário aplicativos maliciosos.Para isso preciso saber os códigos. Entendeu? obrigado..abs

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Os fontes do sistema operacional fica no local onde quase tudo que é *open source* hoje em dia fica, no [GitHub](https://github.com/android). Claro que tem outros espelhamentos, mas este é o mais prático. Uma [alternativa](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/). [Outra](https://android.googlesource.com/).

Este [outro site](https://source.android.com/) deve interessar.

Ter os fontes do Android será pouco útil para o indicado na pergunta. Pegar documentação será bem mais interessante.

Se a intenção é pegar os fontes das aplicações instaladas, não é possível de forma geral, a maioria será de código fechado e as demais terá que ir atrás caso a caso, ou seja, é inviável.

Mesmo que tenha todos os fontes, isso não será útil para fazer as verificações citadas de forma automática. E manualmente não faz muito sentido, nada garante a confiabilidade e é certo que terá vida curta.

Segurança não se obtém através de fontes. Muitos menos dá para fazê-lo em cima de aplicações de terceiros a não ser que esteja disposto a muito trabalho, tenha muito conhecimento e escolha algumas poucas aplicações.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).